# how to handle lazy import in functional component react js avoid import befor need to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Get data from multiple form it causes load more and become slow.
How to avoid import or run code before render the element.

Here the below code run both element . **ProductTitle** and **ProductDemo** style is "none" but it **consol.log("ProductTitle")** and  **consol.log("ProductDemo")** are executed.

**Main js**

```
import { lazy } from 'react';
const ProductTitle = lazy(() => import('./ProductTitle'))
const ProductDemo = lazy(() => import('./ProductDemo'))
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';


const Product = () => {
    const [panel, SetPanel] = useState(0)
    
    return (<div>
        
         <button onClick={()=>SetPanel(panel +1)} >Next panel</button>
       <Suspense fallback={null}  >
        <div style={{ display: (panel === 1) ? 'none' : 'block' }} >
            <ProductTitle />
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: (panel === 2) ? 'none' : 'block' }} >
            <ProductDemo />
        </div>
    </Suspense>
    
    </div>);
}

export default Product;
```

**ProductTitle.js**

```
const ProductTitleA = ({ }) => {
    console.log("ProductTitle")
    
    return <div>
        this ProductTitle Panel
    </div>
}
```

**ProductDemo.js**

```
const ProductDemo = ({ }) => {
    console.log("ProductDemo")

    return <div>
        this ProductDemo Panel
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent those children components from mounting by doing this:

```
import { lazy } from 'react';
const ProductTitle = lazy(() => import('./ProductTitle'))
const ProductDemo = lazy(() => import('./ProductDemo'))
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';


const Product = () => {
    const [panel, SetPanel] = useState(0)
    
    return (<div>
        
         <button onClick={()=>SetPanel(panel +1)} >Next panel</button>
       <Suspense fallback={null}  >
        {(panel === 1) ? <div/> : <div >
            <ProductTitle />
        </div>}
        {(panel === 2) ? <div/> : <div>
            <ProductDemo />
        </div>}
    </Suspense>
    
    </div>);
}

export default Product;
```